# What's the word that means to help someone in return

Tags: vocabulary

Suppose I was helped by someone. Now I want to help him back. What is the word to denote this situation? Please help me!

Answer (score 4):

I want to '[reciprocate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reciprocate)' might work.

> 1 : to make a return for something - we hope to reciprocate for your kindness

'Return the favour' too though it's more than one word.

Answer (score 1):

**repay**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/repay)

> 2. To give back, either in return or in compensation: repay kindness with kindness.

or the idiom: **be square (with one)**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+square+(with+one))

> To no longer be in dispute or disagreement with someone; not indebted
>   to someone anymore